# Querying db change set

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have change set in the form of `IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry>` which I got by calling `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries()`. Is it possible to fire some `linq` query on the top of this changeset in a way we fire against DbContext in `EntityFramework`?

```
var changeSet = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified).ToList();`
```

Comment: what is ChangeTracker here ? which EF version you are using ?

Comment: `DbContext` has a property called `public DbChangeTracker ChangeTracker` which allows us to track the changes made to the DB. `EntityFramework.5.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can execute linq query on IEnumerable type. This kind of query is actually not part of EntityFramework. Its Linq to Objects

Comment: I'm not asking how to find the changeset that I already know.